# Get the index in a structure array

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have this structure array which is in tcl

A={1 2 3} { 4 5 6 }  {7 8 9} {1 4 10}

I would like to get the structure indices which contain the number 4 which should be 2 , and 4 in A;  how could I do it?

Also after i was able to get that indices , i'd like to remove those structures  so that

A={1 2 3}{7 8 9}

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: In wich language JS?

Comment: It is in the tcl language

Comment: Your 'array' doesn't look like a Tcl array. Are you sure you don't mean [list](http://wiki.tcl.tk/440)?

Comment: lappend or list yes , but I wanna know given that I have an array how can reach from the first array (A) to the second one

Comment: Please understand that an array and a list are different things in tcl, different enough that there are separate set of functions that are better suited to each, and depending on what you are trying to do, the best solution will greatly differ...

Answer (score 1):

`[lmap]` can help with that. `[continue]` allows you to skip the item:

```
set A {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9} {1 4 10}}
set B [lmap x $A {
                    if {[lsearch -exact $x 4] >= 0} {
                        continue
                    } else {
                        set x
                    }
                }]
    puts $B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% array set myArr {
        1 {1 2 3}
        2 {4 5 6}
        3 {7 8 9}
        4 {1 4 10}
}
% parray myArr
myArr(1) = 1 2 3
myArr(2) = 4 5 6
myArr(3) = 7 8 9
myArr(4) = 1 4 10
% set num_to_find 4
4
% foreach idx [array names myArr] {
        # Checking if the array contains the number '4'
        if {[lsearch $myArr($idx) $num_to_find]!=-1} {
                # Keep track of the matched indices
                lappend matchIndices $idx
        }
}
% foreach idx $matchIndices {
        # Removing the array index based on the matched indices
        unset myArr($idx)
}
% parray myArr
myArr(1) = 1 2 3
myArr(3) = 7 8 9
%
%
```