# Getting rid of elements in TCL

Tags: arrays, tcl

Let's say I create an array like this:

```
for {set i 1} {$i <=4} {incr i} {
    lappend run "$i [expr $i+1]"
}

puts "$run"

{1 2} {2 3} {3 4} {4 5}
```

Now I'd like to find the elements containing 2 and get rid of them so I will be left with

```
run ={3 4} {4 5}
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Did you not get an answer for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48492970/7552)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: an array is an associative structure in Tcl. What you are creating here is a *list*.

The usual idiom for filtering out elements from a list is to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
set result [lmap item $list {if <test-to-keep> {set item} else continue}]
```

or

```
set result {}
foreach item $list {if <test-to-keep> {lappend result $item}}
```

(The `lmap` command is available in Tcl 8.6 or later, though there is a pure-Tcl version usable in Tcl 8.5 that you can copy and paste into your program mentioned in the links below.)

For this example, you can use this solution:

```
set result [lmap item $run {if {2 ni $item} {set item} else continue}]
```

That is, look at each item and if 2 does not occur in it, keep it.

The `ni` operator is in Tcl 8.5 or later: if you have an older Tcl you should upgrade.

Documentation:
[continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: @glennjackman: oops! I try do that in answer code, but forgot this time. Thanks.

Comment: For those who might have wondered about the earlier version without 'else': it isn’t strictly necessary in this case, but still improves readability. It can be considered somewhat sloppy to omit it.